# Two-way interaction between user-mode app and kernel-mode driver?

Tags: windows, process, kernel, driver

I'm about to write the following interaction:

> - When there is a process about to start, driver will notify user app and then it will wait for response from the app.
> - The app will decide whether or not to allow that process to be created normally or terminated immediately, and send
>   its decision back to the driver.
> - Base on the decision from user app. The driver will then allow or block the process execution.

My question is: What is recommended way to notify user-mode app from driver and then make the driver wait for the response?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the question title. Other than that, very good question.

Comment: What method are you using to detect processes that are about to start?

Comment: -Scott Chamberlain: Sorry for that.
-Harry Johnston: I use psSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx to detect the new process creation. And then I use its callback PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX to do something with that new process.

Comment: I think IOCTL would be best in this situation, in both directions.  The user-mode component would be a bit trickier if decisions for multiple processes must be made in parallel rather than one at a time, but not unreasonably so.  The only doubt in my mind is whether it is legitimate to block in `CreateProcessNotifyEx`, but since it runs in the context of the thread which created the new process I guess it should be OK.

Answer (score 6):

For event notification, you can use a notification event. I.e. the kernel calls IoCreateNotificationEvent and KeSetEvent. The user calls KeWaitForSingleObject. For user-kernel message communication, you can use IOCTL.

Alternatively, you can just use a named pipe for both purpose.

P.S. You can't use PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine() for your purpose because it's only for auditing, but not for prevention/cancellation.

Comment: If he's on Vista and later, he can use [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953(v=vs.85).aspx) to prevent process creation. This technique will work, but he will need to make sure his callback is reentrant and to likely create an event *per process* on which the callback will sleep while userspace makes a decision. Other caveats: make sure not to block process creation before userspace is ready to make decisions.